# When using asyncData with Nuxt, why does the content of my element rerender, but element attributes don't?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have some HTML in my vue file with a v-bind attribute like this:

```
<span>{{ nationalityRankTitleText }}</span>
<span :title="nationalityRankTitleText">Rank #{{ displayedNationalityRank }}</span>
```

I have an asyncData function that calls an API and sets the `player` object for the page's data and the following computed properties that use it:

```
    rankTitleText() {
      let nationalityText = `Ranked #${this.displayedNationalityRank} for players from ${this.player.nationality}`
      let globalText = `Ranked #${this.displayedGlobalRank} globally`
      console.log("RANK OVERRIDES", this.rankOverrides)
      if (this.rankOverrides) {
        console.log(this.player.nationalityRanking)
        if (this.player.nationalityRanking !== this.displayedNationalityRank) {
          nationalityText += ` (Default ranking: ${this.player.nationalityRanking})`
        }
        console.log(this.player.globalRanking)

        if (this.player.globalRanking !== this.displayedGlobalRank) {
          globalText += ` (Default ranking: ${this.player.globalRanking})`
        }
        console.log({ nationalityText, globalText })
        return { nationalityText, globalText }
      }
    },
    rankOverrides() {
      const playerSuccint = this.$store.state.players.succint.find(
        (p) => p.name === this.player.name
      )
      if (playerSuccint && playerSuccint.globalRanking) {
        return {
          globalRanking: playerSuccint.globalRanking,
          nationalityRanking: playerSuccint.nationalityRanking,
        }
      }
    },
    globalRankTitleText() {
      return this.rankTitleText ? this.rankTitleText.globalText : ""
    },
    nationalityRankTitleText() {
      return this.rankTitleText ? this.rankTitleText.nationalityText : ""
    },
    displayedNationalityRank() {
      return this.rankOverrides
        ? this.rankOverrides.nationalityRanking
        : this.player.nationalityRanking
    },
    displayedGlobalRank() {
      return this.rankOverrides
        ? this.rankOverrides.globalRanking
        : this.player.globalRanking
    },
  }
```

If I navigate to the page through the app, everything works fine, but if the first page during app load is this page, then the first span (which is only there for debugging this behaviour) is populated correctly, but the second span has an empty title attribute. The console logs client side show that the computed properties are returning the expected data, and the server side logs show 'undefined' for "RANK OVERRIDES", which I would expect, because the data is taken from a client side $store.

I have tried moving these computed properties into methods to see if it was caused by computed properties, but the behaviour was the same.

Why does the span's content re-render correctly, but the second span's attribute not rerender? This only happens on initial page load too. It's like it's refusing to differ from the SSR content but only for the attribute, not the element content. Even clicking to another page and then clicking the browser back button will cause it to render as expected.

I'm on Nuxt 2.12.2 and I'm using "universal" mode.